# Replace part of string with mutate (in a pipe)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to replace a part of a string (between the first 2 underscores, the first group always being "i") like in the base R example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

d <- tibble(txt = c("i_0000_GES", "i_0000_OISO", "i_0000_ASE1333"),
            repl = c("1111", "1111", "2222"))

str_sub(d$txt, 3, 6) <- d$repl
d

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# txt            repl 
# <chr>          <chr>
# 1 i_1111_GES     1111 
# 2 i_1111_OISO    1111 
# 3 i_2222_ASE1333 2222
```

How can I do that either using `str_sub<-` or another stringr-function?

Comment: Isn't it already doing what you described?

Comment: The problem is that (actually) there are couple dplyr/magrittr-pipes above and below the str_sub. I need to fit the str_sub into a mutate or so.

Comment: something like `d %>% mutate(repl_pipe=str_sub(txt,3,6))`

Comment: Or like this: `d %>%
  mutate(txt = str_replace(txt, '\\d+', repl))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way using `str_sub<-` in a pipe.

```
d %>%
  mutate(txt = `str_sub<-`(txt, 3, 6, value = repl))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  txt            repl 
#  <chr>          <chr>
#1 i_1111_GES     1111 
#2 i_1111_OISO    1111 
#3 i_2222_ASE1333 2222
```

Note that argument `value` is the last, so it must be passed assigned to its name.

Answer (score 4):

```
d %>% 
  mutate(txt = str_replace(txt, '0000', repl))
```

Though probably it will be better with a regex instead of '0000'.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do:

```
d %>%
 mutate(txt = str_replace(txt, str_sub(txt, 3, 6), repl))

  txt            repl 
  <chr>          <chr>
1 i_1111_GES     1111 
2 i_1111_OISO    1111 
3 i_2222_ASE1333 2222
```

Here you first substring and then replace this substring with `repl`.

Or:

```
d %>%
 mutate(txt = {str_sub(txt, 3, 6) <- repl; txt})
```

Answer (score 2):

With `base R` we can use `substring`

```
substring(d$txt, 3, 6) <- d$repl
```